# MongoDB and PlayFramework 2.5 with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.0

I used to develop on PlayFramework with Scala, but at this time I should use Java. That's why I'm looking for the best approach to work with MongoDB for non blocking queries and with object mapping.
It seems like Play! is not so popular among Java developers, so there are not so many options.

I've found MongoDB Reactive Streams Java Driver, but object mapping with it seems so painful.

Could you suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Spring Data MongoDB Library - http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach could be to use [Jongo](http://jongo.org/) and more specifically [PlayJongo](https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/play-jongo) module, according to documentation it provides decent object mapping.